# What is this key called in Xcode Under: View -> Utilities

Tags: xcode

Sorry if this has been answered but, I was not sure what to search for this key in Xcode.

The keys in question are under the `Show File Template Library` and everything else under it.

I know the first two are `control` `alt`, but unsure what the last symbol is and where it is on the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: It's the Command key being drawn over a number, might be a glitch. Just type `Ctrl + Alt + Command + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Combinations of ctrl+option+command + number

[image]